# f_min_lbfgs breaks on quadratic that slices?

Tags: scipy

Following up on this thread [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2008-June/017136.html), where somebody seems to have had the same problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b

def f(x):
    return x[0] ** 2

def g(x):
    return 2 * x[0]

x0 = np.array([-1.])

fmin_l_bfgs_b(f, x0, fprime=g)
```

gives

```
    309         _lbfgsb.setulb(m, x, low_bnd, upper_bnd, nbd, f, g, factr,
    310                        pgtol, wa, iwa, task, iprint, csave, lsave,
--> 311                        isave, dsave)
    312         task_str = task.tostring()
    313         if task_str.startswith(b'FG'):

TypeError: failed to initialize intent(inout|inplace|cache) array, input not an array
```

```

Anybody understand what is going on here? It is not possible to get into any interesting scope level with the debugger.

scipy version on which this is occurring: 0.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the gradient you return in `g` should be an array, not a scalar:

```
>>> def f(x): return x[0] ** 2
>>> def g(x): return 2*x
>>> fmin_l_bfgs_b(f, [-1.0], fprime=g)
(array([ 0.]), 0.0, {'warnflag': 0, 'grad': array([ 0.]), 'funcalls': 2, 'nit': 1, 'task': b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'})
```

Or for something more interesting:

```
>>> def f(x): return (x[0]-3) ** 2
>>> def g(x): return 2*x - 6
>>> fmin_l_bfgs_b(f, [-1.0], fprime=g)
(array([ 3.]), 0.0, {'warnflag': 0, 'grad': array([ 0.]), 'funcalls': 3, 'nit': 2, 'task': b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'})
```

(The `input not an array` message made me think that the routine was expecting something to be an array which wasn't; after that it was simply experimentation.)

Comment: Yup, that's it! The gradient in the first example you give only works because of the 1D initialization. Otherwise a little dangerous ;). Thanks for the answer!